VB.NET import Excel file into VB.NET web-based app using Visual Basic
I am new at ASP.NET.
I need to import an Excel file with multiple tabs into a ASP.NET web-based application (Using a browse button).
I found many tutorial videos using C#. But I want to use Visual Basic instead, since I have no experience with C#.
Can anybody help me?
There is an issue with the "OpenFileDialog".
It says: Using operand of type "OpenFileDialog" must implement System.IDisposable.
I don't know what is missing here.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

In addition to the above comment, we have no context for the error you've mentioned.  Please provide a minimal, reproduceable example so we can better understand the context of that error.

Before you can write code to open the Excel file, you first have to have the user up-load the file to the web server. Remember, a web server can't just open files on someone's computer, as that would be a huge security issue. Hence, when you come to my web site, I can't have a bunch of code looking around for some files like "my banking" or start grabbing say your outlook files or whatever.
So, while developing on your computer, you might be able to pop open a file dialog, but you have to consider your development computer quite different, since both the code, and the web server are running on the one and same computer.
In fact, if you pop the filedialog (which you don't want to use), then in the server room, you would see the file open dialog appearing on the web server!
Like this:

So, you can't use MsgBox, or file dialog, since that going to run and appears on the copy of windows running the web server, not the user's browser. As I noted, during development, it will "appear" to work, but ONLY due to the fact that the web server and your development computer are one and the same.
So, to process any file, including a user supplying a Excel file, you first have to build a page in which a File UpLoad control is placed on the page. The user can then hit select file, and they can then browse their computer files to select a file to upload. Once the file is uploaded to your server, then your code behind can process the file.
So, your first step is to build a file uploading page, and then you have to have created a folder on the web server (in your web project) to save such files to. Keep in mind that two users in theory could upload a file with the same name. And thus you probably should be a table called "UpLoadedFiles", and thus you can keep track of, and separate out files up-loaded by different users.
So, the FileDialog is not available, or better said, such windows commands only run on the SAME computer that the web site and code is running on, not on the end users computer which is using ONLY a browser to interact with the end user. You can't grab, or steal or rummage around on the end user's computer, and if a web based application could access files on the end user's computer, then no one would risk using the internet, since then when you visit my web site, I would start stealing all your files.

Thank you, Albert. That makes sense.I have just started development in ASP.NET. I still have to learn a lot.
